# Kubernetes: Prefer Scheduling On Busier Nodes First

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

We're running a stateful application inside pods on Kubernetes (Azure). This application processes realtime media streams and as such is disruptive if restarted. The number of deployments changes gradually over the period of a few days.

Deployments currently use a `nodeSelector` with a label set to match the worker node pool.

When the Kubernetes cluster has a single node (A), as expected, once the node's requests have been exhausted, the auto-scaler spins up a new node (B).

If pods running on A are evicted or re-deployed, Kubernetes will schedule new pods onto the least busy node.

The problem is that, if/when the overall workload then becomes low enough that node B is no longer necessary, Kubernetes will eventually scale down, but in the process will have to re-deploy all pods from node B onto A.

In our use case, we would want to be able to scale down with the fewest possible pods rescheduled, which seems achievable by somehow prioritising scheduling busier (or perhaps oldest) Kubernetes nodes.

We set `requests` values on each pod template, which as expected prevents a node from scheduling too much work. I've read the documentation on using node taints but I can't see an obvious method to link this into the requests for that node.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

By default Cluster Autoscaler downscale any node below `scale-down-utilization-threshold`. You can play around with this if you want to control the scale down operation.

I would not suggest to deploy pods on the busier node as that may eventually leads to more issues later. Also by default K8s pods are first scheduled and then terminates, so it is perfectly normal to reschedule pods from one node to another.